# How to safely test code updates in pages involved in online payment?

Tags: paypal

I've got a client website in production with both PayPal checkout and PayPal pro credit card payments. I need to update the code sometimes, but I want to be 100% sure that the code works. However I can't test it because I'd have to make a real payment for that.

How do you deal with this?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/test-the-api/ is this helpfull in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can run test transactions against the sandbox box and test the different API calls.  You would need to set up a developer account at developer.paypal.com.  Then create a couple of test accounts such as a seller account and a buyer account.  Generate your API credentials for your test seller account.  Then plug those into your code, and make test API calls against that account.  You can set up your test accounts to mimic your live accounts.